# async/wait, все равно вешается форма

Tags: c#, async-await

Пытаюсь использовать async/wait однако асинхронности не получается (форма всеравно вешается).

```
private async void buttonDownloadUpdateOld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 cUpdate.sResult result = await cUpdate.DownloadOld();
 ...
}
class cUpdate {
public static Task<cUpdate.sResult> DownloadOld()
{
 ...
 return Task.FromResult(result);
}
}
```

После нажатия на кнопку, метод DownloadOld выполняется очень долго, что вешает форму. Но я так понял что при использовании async/wait в таком виде это не должно было произойти. В чем проблема?

Comment: просто вы не правильное его используете :-) стоит добавить, что происходит на месте `...` в методе `DownloadOld`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужен async/await или не нужен?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-async-await-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd)

Comment: В приведенном вопросе дубликате, есть ссылка на видео с объяснением как работает код с async/await.

Comment: Даже в коде метода видно, что вы все делаете синхронно, и только в перед `return` создаете таск, который лишь обертка над результатом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, думаете что создание нового метода и его вызов при помощи слова `await` вынесет вычисления в другой поток. Это не так. Все действия внутри асинхронных методов и тех методов, которые они вызывают, выполняются в потоке UI - а потому вешают форму.

Для того, чтобы вычисления не вешали форму, их надо вынести в отдельный поток при помощи `Task.Run`:

```
cUpdate.sResult result = await Task.Run(() => DownloadOld());
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало. Зря только содержание функции писал, по просьбе другого комменатора :)

Comment: @Ivan Если что, то по поводу корутин можете прочитать вот [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496002/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE) (чтобы у вас сложилось более полное представление об аппаратных и пользовательских потоках).