# Сопрограммы в С++

Tags: c++, c++20, сопрограмма

Недавно техническая спецификация сопрограмм, [Coroutines TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4775.pdf), дошла до состояния "опубликована". Сопрограммы реализованы в MS VC++ 2017.
Что это такое и как их писать?

(Upd: текущая версия Coroutines TS - n4775 от 2018-10-07)
(Upd2: сопрограммы входят в С++20)

Comment: зачем плодить одинаковые вопросы? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496002/Сопрограммы-корутины-coroutine-что-это?rq=1

Answer (score 21):

В С++ сопрограммой называется функция, в которой используются
`co_await`, `co_yield`, `co_return`.

```
Future coroutine(X x) {
  Y y = co_await f(x);
  co_return y;
}
```

Компилятор переписывает тело сопрограммы, превращая ее в машину состояний.
Под данные сопрограммы выделяется память при помощи оператора `new`.

```
Future coroutine(X x) {
  struct CoroutineState {
    Future::promise_type p;
    X x;
    Y y;
    int state = 0;

    void run() {
      switch (state) {
      case 0:
        ...
        state = 1;  // приостановка
        return;
      case 1:       // точка возобновления
        ...
      };
    }
  };
  auto* s = new CoroutineState;
  auto result = s->p.get_return_object();
  s->x = x;
  s->run();
  return result;
}
```

При этом, хотя тело сопрограммы изменяется, она остается функцией.

### promise_type (ч.1)

Компилятор добавляет неявную переменную с типом `Future::promise_type`.
Эта переменная используется для создания результата функции-сопрограммы (`p.get_return_object`), обработки исключений, реализации `co_return`. Также компилятор добавляет точки приостановки в начале и конце сопрограммы, оборачивая тело сопрограммы в следующий код:

```
  Future::promise_type p;
  co_await p.initial_suspend();
  try {
    // тело сопрограммы
    Y y = co_await f(x);
    co_return y;
    // конец тела сопрограммы
  } catch(...) { p.unhandled_exception(); }
final_suspend:
  co_await p.final_suspend();
```

### co_return

В сопрограмме нельзя использовать `return y;`, вместо него используется `co_return y;`,
который заменяется на

```
p.return_value(y);
goto final_suspend;
```

Если сопрограмма не предусматривает возврат значения по завершении, то используется `co_return;` (без выражения) и соответствующая ему функция `p.return_void();`.
При этом не обязательно писать `co_return;` в конце сопрограммы.

### co_await

Приостановка сопрограммы происходит в операторе `co_await`.
Код `Y y = co_await f(x);` заменяется на

```
auto e = f(x);
if (!e.await_ready()) {
  ... приостановка ...
  std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h = ...;
  if (e.await_suspend(h)) return;
resume:  // точка возобновления для h.resume()
  ... возобновление ...
}
Y y = e.await_resume();
```

Стандартная библиотека предоставляет класс `coroutine_handle`, который позволяет возобновить приостановленную сопрограмму.
Функция `f` принимает его через `e.await_suspend(h)`. Когда значение `y` будет вычислено, она должна вызвать `h.resume()`, и вернуть вычисленное значение через `e.await_resume()`.

Для stackless сопрограммы, функия `f` может быть написана следующим образом:

```
// Общие данные фонового потока и Awaiter.
struct SharedState {
  std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h;
  Y value;
  std::atomic<bool> is_ready;
};

// Тип результата f
struct Awaiter {
  std::shared_ptr<SharedState> s;

  bool await_ready() { return false; }
  bool await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h) {
    s->h = h;
    return !s->is_ready.exchange(true);  // True если фоновый поток уже завершился
                                         // и у нас есть s->value
  }
  Y await_resume() { return s->value; }
};

Awaiter f(X x) {
  auto s = std::make_shared<SharedState>();
  std::thread([=]{  // Запуск фонового потока для вычислений
    s->value = ...;
    if (s->is_ready.exchange(true)) {  // True, если await_suspend уже была вызвана
                                       // и у нас есть s->h
      s->h.resume();
    }
  }).detach();
  return Awaiter{s};
}
```

Для stackful сопрограммы (например Fibers в Windows), `await_suspend` должна сама замораживать поток (`SwitchToFiber`). Точка возобновления будет внутри `await_suspend`, поэтому она должна возвращать `false`.

### promise_type (ч.2)

Минимальный тип возвращаемого значения сопрограммы выглядит так:

```
struct Future {
  struct promise_type {
    Future get_return_object() { return {this}; }
    std::experimental::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::experimental::suspend_always final_suspend() { return {}; }
    void return_value(Y& y) { y_ptr = &y; }
    std::atomic<Y*> y_ptr = nullptr;
  };

  std::shared_ptr<promise_type> promise;

  static void Deleter(promise_type* p) {
    auto h = std::experimental::coroutine_handle<P>::from_promise(*p);
    h.destroy();  // удаляет CoroutineState
  }

  Future(promise_type* p) : promise(p, Deleter) {}

  Y BlockingGet() {
    while (promise->y_ptr == nullptr) Sleep(1);  // ждем
    return *promise->y_ptr;  // дождались вызова p.return_value(y)
  }
};
```

`Future::promise_type` должен иметь `get_return_object`, `initial_suspend`, `final_suspend` и либо `return_void` либо `return_value`.

Для реализации `initial_suspend` и `final_suspend` можно использовать стандартные `suspend_never` и `suspend_always`, которые возвращают в `await_ready` значения `true` и `false` соответственно.

Такая сопрограмма будет всегда засыпать в конце.

От самого `Future` требуется только чтобы он удалил сопрограмму через `h.destroy()`.

`Future` может (но не обязан) повторять интерфейс `Awaiter`, чтобы быть совместимым с `co_await`.

### await_transform и operator co_await

Для выражения `a` в `co_await a` могут применяться дополнительные преобразования:

- если выражение `p.await_transform(a)` валидно, то `a` заменяется на `p.await_transform(a)`;
- если для типа `a` есть оператор `operator co_await`, то `a` заменяется на `operator co_await(a)`;
- если в результате получилось *prvalue*, то оно копируется во временную переменную, иначе используется как есть.

Таким образом возможен вариант

```
auto& e = operator co_await(p.await_transform(f(x)));
if (!e.await_ready()) { ... }
```

Например можно определить `operator co_await(std::chrono::duration)` и писать `co_await 10ms;`.

### Выделение памяти

Объект `CoroutineState` создается при помощи `new`. Однако, если есть функция `p.get_return_object_on_allocation_failure()`, то будет сгенерирован следующий код:

```
auto* s = new(std::nothrow) CoroutineState;
if (!s) {
  return p.get_return_object_on_allocation_failure();
}
auto result = s->p.get_return_object();
```

Это позволяет обрабатывать ошибки выделения памяти.

Также, аргументы сопрограммы могут участвовать в выделении памяти.
Для сопрограммы `Future coro(A1 a1, A2 a2)`, если есть функция `operator new(std::size_t, A1, A2)`, то она будет вызвана вместо оператора `new` по умолчанию.

### promise_type (ч.3), coroutine_traits

Компилятор использует класс coroutine_traits для получения `promise_type`.

Для сопрограммы `Future coro(A1 a1, A2 a2)` будет использован тип `std::experimental::coroutine_traits<Future, A1, A2>::promise_type`.

Реализация по-умолчанию выдает `Future::promise_type`, однако это может быть переопределено пользователем.

### co_yield

`co_yield e;` эквивалентен `co_await p.yield_value(e);` и используется в генераторах - специальных сопрограммах которые предназначены для выдачи последовательности значений.

## Примеры

- [Как использовать сопрограммы С++ с Boost.Asio?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/703715/177684)

Comment: Вопрос необходимости отстается открытым. Допустим, у меня есть 10 действий, которые я хочу сделать в одном потоке. У некоторых из них есть зависимость одних от других, у некоторых нет, это не важно. 
Я могу написать выполнить эти 10 действий потоком, и они будут им выполнены. Или я могу написать несколько ко-рутин, чтобы подзапутать выполнение (не нарушая зависимостей), добавить в код новые абстракции, усложнить код. И в итоге в одном потоке будут выполнены те же самые 10 действий.
Вопрос, зачем мне вообще нужны корутины тогда?

Comment: так корутины же не дают асинхронности. Действия по прежнему будут выполняться в одном потоке. Как бы в итоге асинхронно 10 действий не распределили время выполнения потока, это будут всё те же 10 действий выполненных потоком.
единственно возможное приминение, которое мне видно, это, возможно, взаимодействие с внешними источниками сигналов, от UI, который надо периодически обновлять и слушать, до каких-то сокетов, однако в этом случае всё равно придется синхронизировать доступ до каких-то переменных, и издержек синхронизации не избежать. Так почему тогда не использовать потоки?

Comment: я потому и спрашиваю, что не знаю, но хочу узнать, зачем их ввели)

Comment: Наверное, для лучшего понимания нужен какой-то "законченный" и логически простой (но не слишком искусственный, например, что-то вроде парсера, взаимодействующего  с лексером на одной страничке) пример с 2-мя (или 3-мя, включая main?) сопрограммами (и пояснениями, тут запускаем, в этом цикле возобновляем и вот так используем очередной результат, а вот так завершаем) Тогда может уточняющие вопросы хотя бы появятся. Я же, пока совсем не понял, как всем этим предполагают пользоваться.