# Внутренности сопрограмм с++

Tags: c++, сопрограмма

Пытаюсь понять работу сопрограмм в `с++17`. Что это такое и по что оно нужно - более-менее понятно из ответа к вопросу [Сопрограммы в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702454/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%A1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Однако, после рассмотрения ответа к тому вопросу, а так же [примера использования сопрограмм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703715/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%A1-%D1%81-boost-asio?noredirect=1&lq=1), у меня возник ряд вопросов.

1. Обязана ли сопрограмма возвращать фьючер или же она может не возвращать ничего, а просто иметь внутри себя `co_await`, `co_yield` или `co_return`? Все, что возвращает фьючер, есть сопрограмма?
2. Каким образом происходит приостановка сопрограммы? Это целиком и полностью работа компилятора по разворачиванию `co_await` или же дополнительно к остальному коду предъявляются какие-то требования?
3. При запуске следующего кода гарантируется ли порядок вывода в консоль значений? Если да, то правильно ли я понимаю, что программа на каждой итерации цикла будет ждать завершения операции вывода? Можно ли в это время выполнять другую полезную работу? Если можно, то хочется увидеть пример.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
   {
       co_await AsyncWrite(i);   // Пусть AsyncWrite асинхронно
                                 // выводит переданное ей число в консоль
   }
   ```

Comment: В C++17 нет сопрограмм, а ответ Abyx говорит о несуществующих на текущий момент в стандарте C++ вещах.